# Visual Studio 2008 give error of component not found

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm been using VS 2008 "forever". Rebooted yesterday and now I get an error that says a component can not be found. This is on the devenv.exe executable and is the first thing that is displayed.

I've reinstalled, I've uninstalled and installed VS2008 twice and still get the same error.

Searching on the net shows people having a similar problem with a missing alt dll, but I don't have VC++ loaded and that dll is not missing. Have ran the depends.exe and the only missing dll is dwmapi.dll, which isn't even needed on a Windows XP os. Tried using /safemode and it still fails. Using /log flag shows nothing too.

I need some more ideas or a way to find out what exactly is missing.

Thanks Dwight

**edit:** the error was that atl90.dll was missing in one of the C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.atl* directories.

Don't even hav vc++ added.

Comment: you have not told us which is missing so far :)

Comment: If I knew what was missing, it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the atl90.dll was missing in one of the C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.atl* directories.

Don't even hav vc++ added.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go off of from your question, but have you tried:

- If Vista/7: Launching VS in administrator mode (via the shell link properties)?
- Turning off any Anti-Virus software?
- Clearing the system event logs and temporary directories?

Comment: Question says Windows xp and Visual studio 2008.  Don't have a lot more to tell since nothing gets logged.  I tried turning Mccrashy off but no go.   It's a company pc so turn programs off can be a pain.